# Simultaneity bias when a variable enters lagged into equation

Tags: simultaneous-equation

I'm fairly new to econometrics and I'm trying to understand the simultaneity bias in my investigation:

I'm investigating to what extent salary influences performance in Major League Baseball using panel data of individual players and a fixed effects estimator.

Salary and performance are determined simultaneously:

(1) Performance(i,t) = a + B*Salary(i,t) + e

(2) Salary(i,t) = a + B*Performance(i,t-1) + u

In words, performance at time t is determined by salary at time t with no reverse causation since salary is set before the season starts and does not change throughout the season. Therefore, salary at time t cannot respond to performance at time t and instead is determined by prior performance.

My question is: does simultaneity bias still exist despite the fact that an increase in performance at time t can be fully attributed to an increase in salary at time t (and not vice versa) holding all else constant and if so how?

Comment: From what i know about Major League Baseball, I'd be rather surprised if your model is very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simultaneity bias if and only if (i) error $e$ is a white noise (i.e. it does not has autocorrelation), and (ii) error in both equations are independent.

Define Performance as $P$, and Salary as $S$. Your system is:

$$P_{i,t} = a + bS_{i,t} + \epsilon_{i,t}$$
$$S_{i,t} = c + dP_{i,t-1} + \mu_{i,t}$$

The condition for exogeneity of $S_{i,t}$ in the first equation **is defined as**

$$E(\epsilon_{i,t}|S_{i,t})=0$$

Using the [Law of Total Expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) (plus the inconsequential assumption that $E\left(\epsilon_{i,t}\right)=0$), this condition can be redefined as

$$E(\epsilon_{i,t}\cdot S_{i,t})=0$$

Replacing the second equation of the system in the above condition gives:

$$E\left(\epsilon_{i,t}(c + dP_{i,t-1} + \mu_{i,t})\right)=0$$

This gives three summation terms:

1. $E\left(c\epsilon_{i,t}\right)=cE\left(\epsilon_{i,t}\right)=0$
2. $E(d\epsilon_{i,t}P_{i,t-1})$, which is zero if $\epsilon_{i,t}$ does not have autocovariance. This is because, when replacing $P_{i,t-1}$ with the lagged version of equation 1, you get the term

$$E(\epsilon_{i,t}\epsilon_{i,t-1})$$

which is equal to the first order covariance of the process $\epsilon_{i,t}$.

3. $E\left(\epsilon_{i,t}\mu_{i,t}\right)$, which is zero if the error terms in both equations are independent.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear and concise answer. An additional question: if the error term has autocorrelation, will the use of autocorrelation consistent standard errors correct for the simultaneity bias?

Comment: No. That is an entirely different problem. That correction is about obtaining an **efficient** estimator. Yet, the estimator must be **consistent** in the first place. The problem with simultaneity bias is that the estimator is **inconsistent**. A solution however is to rewrite your system as an autodistributed lag, by replacing the second equation into the former, iterating. Can add this to the answer, once I have time.